# How can I select multiple buttons without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, class, button

I have 5 true/false statements and need to have 5 buttons selected separately as answers. The text will be a statement and the user should choose whether it is true or false in all 5 questions. The problem is only one button gets selected and I need to fix this with only using HTML and CSS without JS
The code is:

```css
button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #222222;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  transition: box-shadow .2s,-ms-transform .1s,-webkit-transform .1s,transform .1s;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-color: #000000;
  transform: scale(.90);
}

.t1:focus, .t2:focus, .t3:focus, .t4:focus, .t5:focus {
    background-color: green;
}
.f1:focus, .f2:focus, .f3:focus, .f4:focus, .f5:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="json.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Text</p>
    <button type="button" name = "q1" id="q1t" class="t1" value="1">True</button>
    <button type="button" name = "q1" id="q1f" class="f1" value="0">False</button>

    <p>Text</p>
    <button type="button" name = "q2" id="q2t" class="t2" value="1">True</button>
    <button type="button" name = "q2" id="q2f" class="f2" value="0">False</button>

    <p>Text</p>
    <button type="button" name = "q3" id="q3t" class="t3" value="1">True</button>
    <button type="button" name = "q3" id="q3f" class="f3" value="0">False</button>

    <p>Text</p>
    <button type="button" name = "q4" id="q4t" class="t4" value="1">True</button>
    <button type="button" name = "q4" id="q4f" class="f4" value="0">False</button>

    <p>Text</p>
    <button type="button" name = "q5" id="q5t" class="t5" value="1">True</button>
    <button type="button" name = "q5" id="q5f" class="f5" value="0">False</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buttons don't have a selected state. Perhaps you should be using radio input groups.

Comment: Protip: You don't need vendor prefixes for [transition](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition) or [transform](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the button appearance based on the ":focus" state.  So when focus shifts to another button (due to clicking), focus is lost.

I assume after all the questions are answered you're going to want to submit a form.  Buttons alone won't work for this - you need radio buttons to be able to store the state of the button.  Fortunately, it's pretty straightforward to make radios look like buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use radio-buttons, styled as buttons:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
label:hover {
  background-color: #dfd;
}

input[type="radio"]:focus + label {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #bfb;
    border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
    <input type="radio" name="test1" id="test11">
    <label for="test11">True</label>
    <input type="radio" name="test1" id="test12">
    <label for="test12">False</label>

    <p>Text</p>
    <input type="radio" name="test2" id="test21">
    <label for="test21">True</label>
    <input type="radio" name="test2" id="test22">
    <label for="test22">False</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly experienced myself, but I'm not sure if  will get you the functionality you want without Javascript. I know you could get this working with `<input type = "radio">` (info on how to group radio buttons [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)). Styling them [is a bit of a pain, though](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp).